# Resizing qtree to fit pagewidth

Tags: trees, qtree

I'm trying to learn `qtree` but I still couldn't figure out how to resize to fit the page width. I would like to avoid cutting the tree.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage{qtree}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\caption{{\'{A}rvore de Instala{\c{c}}{\~{o}}es} Portu{\'{a}}rias.}

\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
\Tree [.{\textbf{Sistema Portu{\'{a}}rio} \\ Lei 12.815/2013 \\ Decreto 8.033}
        [.{Instala{\c{c}}{\~{o}}es} [.Organizado {Porto P{\'{u}}blico \\ de Pequeno Porte} {Esta{\c{c}}{\~{a}}o \\ de Transbordo}  ] [.Privado [.{\textbf{Registro} \\ Resolu{\c{c}}{\~{a}}a Normativa n. 13}  {IP4\\DNIT} 
{ETC\\ Petrobr{\'{a}}s} ] ] ]
        [.{Regula{\c{c}}{\~{a}}o} Concess{\~{a}}o Arrendamento Autoriza{\c{c}}{\~{a}}o Delega{\c{c}}{\~{a}}o ] ]

\end{minipage}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: Qtree code result]

Comment: Welcome! You can use `\resizebox`. It is evil, but it will work. Can you see the image you uploaded?

Comment: Hi, no i can't.

Comment: Not just me, then, and not just images I upload. That's something, at least ;).

Comment: I don't think uploading again will help. It seems to be a general problem.

Comment: Really good. Added \usepackage{graphicx} and \centering \resizebox{0.9\textwidth}{!}{ something something something }

Comment: Have you checked the `qtree` documentation? "How do I make my tree fit in the page" is the first question on the FAQ, and it suggests several things you can do. (It's not a complete list: `\resizebox` and "use a different package" are not among them :-)).

Comment: I don't mind to follow other solutions. :)

Comment: @alexis There are other reasons to move to one of the newer, more flexible and powerful packages, though e.g. `tikz-qtree`, `forest` etc. I used `qtree` extensively at one point, but I wouldn't use it now.

Comment: @cfr, I'm just saying it's not necessary to switch packages just to get a tree to fit in the page.

Comment: @alexis You could write an answer. Something `qtree`-based with resizing sounds good.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although you can resize the diagram, this is not recommended as you will end up with a mish-mash of font sizes.

Instead, I would recommend using a newer, more powerful package to draw the tree. Forest specialises in compact trees such as this:

[image: Compact tree]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \caption{Árvore de Instalações Portuárias.}
  \begin{forest}
    [\textbf{Sistema Portuário}\\Lei 12.815/2013\\Decreto 8.033
      [Instalações
        [Organizado
          [Porto Público\\de Pequeno\\Porte
          ]
          [Estação\\de Transbordo
          ]
        ]
        [Privado
          [\textbf{Registro}\\Resoluçãa\\Normativa n.\ 13
            [IP4\\DNIT]
            [ETC\\Petrobrás]
          ]
        ]
      ]
        [{Regulação}
          [Concessão]
          [Arrendamento]
          [Autorização]
          [Delegação]
        ]
    ]
  \end{forest}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Based on user cfr,

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\caption{{\'{A}rvore de Instala{\c{c}}{\~{o}}es} Portu{\'{a}}rias.}
\centering
\resizebox{0.9\textwidth}{!}{
\Tree [.{\textbf{Sistema Portu{\'{a}}rio} \\ Lei 12.815/2013 \\ Decreto 8.033}
        [.{Instala{\c{c}}{\~{o}}es} [.Organizado {Porto P{\'{u}}blico \\ de Pequeno Porte} {Esta{\c{c}}{\~{a}}o \\ de Transbordo}  ] [.Privado [.{\textbf{Registro} \\ Resolu{\c{c}}{\~{a}}a Normativa n. 13}  {IP4\\DNIT} 
{ETC\\ Petrobr{\'{a}}s} ] ] ]
        [.{Regula{\c{c}}{\~{a}}o} Concess{\~{a}}o Arrendamento Autoriza{\c{c}}{\~{a}}o Delega{\c{c}}{\~{a}}o ] ]

}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It is more usual to ask the person who helped to answer rather than taking the credit for it .... (I'm not bothered - it was just an off-the-cuff comment from the top of my head, but people may get annoyed in other cases.)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I thought it would be inapropried to demand a complete answer.